# Multiplying, subtracting and dividing binary numbers give wrong answers

Tags: swift, binary, decimal, calculator

I'm making a binary calculator app.
No buildtime issues but in the app only adding binary numbers give the right answer, multiplying, subtracting and dividing don't.

- Dividing - every answer = 1 (1010-0001 = 1; 10101010-1010 = 1)
- Multiplying - every answer is wrong, (11111 x 101010 = 1111000001, should be 10100010110)
- Subtracting - every answer = 0 ( 1010-0001  = 0; 1010101-0001 = 0)

I tried making the code more explanatory and it worked in the playground (ending with print() ) but when I changed the apps code, the answers were the same.

```
    var numberOnScreen:Int = 0;
    var previousNumber:Int = 0;
    var doingMath = false
    var operation = 0;
    var decimal = 0;
    var decimal1 = 0;
    var binary:String = ""
    var binary1:String = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func Numbers(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if doingMath == true
    {
        label.text = String(sender.tag-1)
        numberOnScreen = Int(label.text!)!
        doingMath = false

    }
    else
    {
        label.text = label.text! + String(sender.tag-1)
        numberOnScreen = Int(label.text!)!
    }
    }
    @IBAction func buttons(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if label.text != "" && sender.tag != 6 && sender.tag != 8
    {
        previousNumber = Int(label.text!)!
        binary = "\(previousNumber)"
        decimal = Int(binary, radix: 2)!
        binary1 = "\(numberOnScreen)"
        decimal1 = Int(binary1, radix: 2)!

       operation = sender.tag
        doingMath = true;
    }
        else if sender.tag == 8
    {
        if operation == 3 //adding
        {
            label.text = String((decimal + decimal1), radix: 2)
        }
        else if operation == 4 //subtracting
        {
            label.text = String((decimal - decimal1), radix: 2)
        }
        else if operation == 5 //multiplying
        {
            label.text = String((decimal * decimal1), radix: 2)
            }
        else if operation == 7 //dividing
        {
            label.text = String((decimal / decimal1), radix: 2)            
        }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code as far as the arithmetic operations are concerned). However, you might have a flaw in your logic when you use the `sender`s tag value or accessing the `label`'s value. Put some print statements in there and see what exactly is being subtracted, added, multiplied, and divided. You might be working with wrong values

Comment: I've added a few print statements and it turns out that the code thinks that binary = binary1 but they have completely different variables. I checked also that those variables do have different values. Any ideas why is that?

Comment: Well in the code that you've shared, `binary = previousNumber` and `binary1 = numberOnScreen`. How are the `previousNumber` & `numberOnScreen` being set?

Comment: previousNumber:Int = 0

         numberOnScreen:Int = 0

         label.text = String(sender.tag-1)

         numberOnScreen = Int(label.text!)!

         previousNumber = Int(label.text!)!

Comment: @Malik Sorry for bad formatting, I couldn't get it right :/

Comment: Since I don't know the business logic, It will be a bit trick to troubleshoot this issue. One thing I know for sure is that there is some sort of wrong logic being used but will need more information to pin point to actual issue. For starters, what is the corresponding value for each tag value? (like 3 is add, 4 is subtract etc)